# Running protractor e2e with custom build and serve configuration

Tags: angular, jenkins, protractor

I have

```
Angular : 8
Protractor: 5.4
```

Added configurations for build in angular.json

```
project:build:e2e
```

and Serve configuration

```
project:serve:e2e
```

For E2E testing using below command we would like to use environment.prod.ts, however it always runs project:serve

```
ng e2e --configuration=e2e
```